# How do I easily find the sum of variables corresponding to a dynamic string variable?

Tags: php

I'm completely stumped on how to accomplish my task programmatically.

I have a dynamically changing alpha string variable named $string.  I have corresponding values set to each letter in the alphabet.  I need to be able to automatically calculate the value of $total_string_length based on the letters within the $string variable.

```
$string = "jack"

$A_length = 1000;
$B_length = 500;
$C_length = 200;
$D_length = 1000;
$E_length = 1400;
$F_length = 100;
$G_length = 5000;
$H_length = 2000;
$I_length = 600;
$J_length = 8000;
$K_length = 8000;
etc...

$total_string_length = $J_length  + $A_length + $C_length + $K_length
```

How do I easily substitute the corresponding alpha letter variable values to find the $total_string_length ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: For starters, don't use individual variables. Use something like `$lengths = ['a' => 1000, 'b' => 500, ...]`.

Comment: You could use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), but it would make more sense to use an array for the values of the individual letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP can use dynamic variable names.

```
$string = "jack";

$A_length = 1000;
$B_length = 500;
$C_length = 200;
$D_length = 1000;
$E_length = 1400;
$F_length = 100;
$G_length = 5000;
$H_length = 2000;
$I_length = 600;
$J_length = 8000;
$K_length = 8000;

$output = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
    $varName = strtoupper($string[$i]) . "_length";
    $output += $$varName; // notice the double `$` charaters
}

echo $output;
```

In the above code snippet, the  value of the `$varName` variable is the name of the variable we want to get the number from. If `$varName` is `A_length` then `$$varName` is equivalent to `$A_length`.

However, it's better to store your number in an array instead of a list of separated variables.

Answer (score 0):

Not much into PHP, But in Java we can do something as below:

1. Create an integer array of size 26 (number of letters in the alphabet) and load the length value of each variable's first character based on its index i.e.,

   ```java
   intArr[(int)"A_length".charAt(0) - 65] = 1000;
   ```
2. Iterate through the characters of the string and get the value as stated below:

   ```java
   for ( char ch : string.tocharArray() ) {
           sum += intArr[(int)ch - 65 ];
   }
   ```

Comment: Answers about Java don't really answer questions about PHP.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: seems like it was not of much help. My intention was to just give an overview of the logic so that something can be figured out.

Comment: @Dev-iL- Thanks for formatting the response. I was struggling with that.